# Make a click event in Tkinter

Tags: python, button, tkinter

I'm trying do a very simple task: Make a Button click in Tkinter.

I have an array of Buttons and, when I finish an event, I want to make a Button click event in one of my buttons.

I thought it should be as simple as `buttons[2].click()`, but that doesn't do anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try calling `.invoke()` on the button

Comment: Thanks, I know it was something simple :)
For some reason, All my searches for "click" did not took me to the invoke option.